# Conjugate Gradient in Eigen for non positive definite matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

In the [description of the CG method](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ConjugateGradient.html) in the Eigen library one can find the statement:

> This class allows to solve for A.x = b linear problems using an iterative conjugate gradient algorithm. The matrix A must be selfadjoint.

However in the literature the conjugate gradient method is typically presented for real symmetric positive-definite matrices. 
Examples shows that Eigen CG actually work for non positive definite matrices that matlab [pcg](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html) cannot handle.

For example running the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers" 
#include "Eigen/Eigenvalues"

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    const int N = 10;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor>  S(N,N);
    const Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,2> sources = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,2);

    for(size_t iEx = 0; iEx < 4; iEx++ )
    {
        std::cout<<"EX "<<iEx<<":\n";
        if(iEx == 0)
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
                    S(i,j) = S(j,i) = 1./std::sqrt((sources.row(i) - sources.row(j)).squaredNorm() +1.);
        if(iEx == 1)
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
                    S(i,j) = S(j,i) = (sources.row(i) - sources.row(j)).norm();
        if(iEx == 2)
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
                    S(i,j) = S(j,i) = sources.row(i).dot(sources.row(j));

        if(iEx == 3)
            S = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N).selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>();

        Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor> Sadj = S.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>();
        std::cout<<"\tIS SELFADJOINT: "<<((Sadj.array() == S.array()).all()?"YES\n":"NO\n");
        Eigen::EigenSolver< Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor> > eigensolver(S);
        std::cout<<"\tNUMBER OF NEGATIVE EIGEN VALUES: "<<(eigensolver.eigenvalues().real().array() < 0.).count()<<" OUT OF "<<N<<"\n";

        const Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1> xExact = Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(N);
        const Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1> b = S * xExact;

        Eigen::ConjugateGradient< Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Lower|Eigen::Upper, Eigen::IdentityPreconditioner> cg(S);
        cg.setMaxIterations(3000);
        cg.setTolerance(1e-10);

        const Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1> xSol = cg.solve(b);
        std::cout<<"\tITERATIONS       : " << cg.iterations() << "\n";
        std::cout<<"\tESTIMATED ERROR  : " << cg.error()      << "\n";

        std::cout<<"\tNORM 2 ERROR     : "<<(xExact-xSol).norm()<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"\tNORM 2 AVG ERROR : "<<(xExact-xSol).norm()/static_cast<double>(N)<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"\tNORM INF ERROR   : "<<(xExact-xSol).lpNorm<Eigen::Infinity>()<<"\n";
        std::cout<<std::flush;
    }
}
```

Gives the output:

```
EX 0:
        IS SELFADJOINT: YES
        NUMBER OF NEGATIVE EIGEN VALUES: 0 OUT OF 10
        ITERATIONS       : 11
        ESTIMATED ERROR  : 1.01319e-11
        NORM 2 ERROR     : 2.49293e-10
        NORM 2 AVG ERROR : 2.49293e-11
        NORM INF ERROR   : 1.20759e-10
EX 1:
        IS SELFADJOINT: YES
        NUMBER OF NEGATIVE EIGEN VALUES: 9 OUT OF 10
        ITERATIONS       : 10
        ESTIMATED ERROR  : 2.43788e-12
        NORM 2 ERROR     : 1.77969e-11
        NORM 2 AVG ERROR : 1.77969e-12
        NORM INF ERROR   : 8.2061e-12
EX 2:
        IS SELFADJOINT: YES
        NUMBER OF NEGATIVE EIGEN VALUES: 4 OUT OF 10
        ITERATIONS       : 1
        ESTIMATED ERROR  : 1.72812e-16
        NORM 2 ERROR     : 2.97281
        NORM 2 AVG ERROR : 0.297281
        NORM INF ERROR   : 1.45547
EX 3:
        IS SELFADJOINT: YES
        NUMBER OF NEGATIVE EIGEN VALUES: 5 OUT OF 10
        ITERATIONS       : 9
        ESTIMATED ERROR  : 7.73713e-14
        NORM 2 ERROR     : 8.55003e-14
        NORM 2 AVG ERROR : 8.55003e-15
        NORM INF ERROR   : 5.29576e-14
```

Example 0 is a positive definite matrix.
Examples 1 2 3 are symmetric NON positive definite matrices. Examples 1 and 3 are solved correctly whereas example 2 fails.

The [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/9584fac85b3fc228d424b7f1e4a0c3e16c549aaa/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/ConjugateGradient.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) looks similar to classical CG implementations.

QUESTIONS:
Is there any trick in Eigen that allows handling non-positive definite matrices? 
Is example 2 not respecting some requirements in order to be solved by Eigen with CG?

Comment: That seems to be a shortcoming from the doc. The fact it worked on some non positive problems is likely just luck.

Answer (score 3):

The CG *can* be used for solving systems with matrices that aren't positive definite and symmetric, in the following way: the CG algorithm must be applied to the system **[A]T[A]x=[A]Tb** where [A]T stands for the transposed matrix. In that case **[A]T[A]** is symmetric and positive definite unless **[A]** is singular. A drawback is that **[A]T[A]** has the original matrix condition ratio squared, so if cond(**[A]**) exceeds appox. 10e7, the CG iterations are unlikely to converge at all, and/or the resulting vector **x** may not have any significant digits. If your matrix is reasonably "good" in numerical sense, say  cond(**[A]**) doesn't exceed about 10e3 or 10e4, you may expect the iterations to converge, and the solution will have several significant digits. The following publication contains source codes implementing such algorithm: [https://www.amazon.com/Solution-Systems-Algebraic-Equations-Matrices/dp/0646990454](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0646990454)

Comment: You should use [LSCG](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1LeastSquaresConjugateGradient.html) in that case, however (and it does actually not require `A` to be symmetric or non-singular).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, this does not answer my questions. Apparently (looking at the code) the ConjugateGradient class in the Eigen library is not using such a trick. As the user chtz said, such a strategy is implemented in another class of the Eigen library. 
Probably @ggael is right, Eigen can solve such systems just out of luck. But it would still be nice to understand why especially because other codes fails in all the above non-positive definite examples.

Comment: @FlavioG analyzing why specific CG implementations happen to work with what kinds of matrices is probably a bit out of scope here.